Suppose $f(xy+f(x))=xf(y)+2$ for every $x,y\in \Bbb{R}$. Show $f(x)$ is a linear function.
Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous real function defined on $\Bbb{R}$ which is not constantly zero, and $$f(xy+f(x))=xf(y)+2$$ for every $x,y\in \Bbb{R}$. Show $f(x)$ is a strictly monotonic linear function.
What I have tried:
Let $y=0$, then $f(f(x))=f(0)x+2$,$\quad f(f(0))=2$.
Suppose $f(0)=0$, then we get the contradiction $f(0)=2$ which means $f(0) \neq 0$.
Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$, then $$f(f(x))=f(f(y)) \implies f(0)x+2=f(0)y+2 \implies x=y$$
It follows that $f(x)$ is one-to-one on $\Bbb{R}$.
Assume $f(x)$ is not strictly monotonic, then there exists $x<y<z$ such that $f(x)<f(y)>f(z)$ (or $f(x)>f(y)<f(z)$), let $M = \max\{f(x),f(z)\}$, pick $c \in (M,f(y))$,by the continuity of $f(x)$, there exists $$\xi\in (x,y), \eta \in (y,z)$$ such that $f(\xi)=f(\eta)=c$ which is contrary to the $1-1$ of $f(x)$. Hence $f(x)$ is strictly monotonic on $\Bbb{R}$.
But I can’t figure out how to prove $f(x)$ is a linear function.
Update:
Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion: $f(xy+f(x))=xf(y)+2$.
$$P(f(1),x) \implies f( f(1)x+f(f(1)))=f(1)f(x)+2 $$
$$P(f(x),1) \implies f(f(x)+f(f(x)))=f(x)f(1)+2 $$
$$f( f(1)x+f(f(1)))=f(f(x)+f(f(x))) \implies f(1)x+f(f(1))=f(x)+f(f(x))$$ that is,$$f(1)x+f(0)+2=f(x)+f(0)x+2$$
Hence, $f(x)=[f(1)-f(0)]x+f(0)$

How does the last part show that $f(x)$ is strictly monotonic, which means that $(x-y)(f(x) - f(y) ) $ always has the same sign? You've only shown that it is one-to-one.

I think you mean «affine function» instead of «linear function». The only (real) affine solution $f(x) = a x + b$ seems to be $f(x) = x + 1$.

@Calvin Lin Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $R$. I have updated my question for this.

I haven't attempted to show that $f$ is differentiable.  But if it is, then evaluating $\left. \frac{d}{dx} \right\vert_{x=0}$ on both sides of the functional equation yields $f'(f(0))(y + f'(0)) = f(y)$, i.e., $f$ is linear.  I realize that proving that $f$ is differentiable is the hard part, of course.

"which is not constantly zero" - this is strange requirement, zero function does not satify the equation anyway.

As for a solution: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1413224p7950916 (continuity is also not needed)

Let $c=f(-2/f(0)).$ What is the value of $f(c)$? Set $x=c$ in the original equation. That gives a nice functional equation that you might be able to solve.
